# XML to Excel parse error

Tags: xml, excel, parsing, attributes, pseudocode

I am trying to export an XML file to excel but I keep getting the following error, "XML parse error" the details tab then refers to "invalid syntax for an xml deceleration"

When i run the XML code through a validation tool it highlights the error:

Click on  to jump to the error. In the document, you can point at  with your mouse to see the error message. 
Errors in file HorseRacing.dtd: 
    1:  53  No more pseudo attributes are allowed.

HorseRacing.dtd
1

I've tried removing the ? and importing but that doesn't work and when i run the code through the validation tool with the / removed I get the opposite error, this time saying:

```
1:  53  A pseudo attribute name is expected.
```

Has anyone got a suggestion as to how I can resolve this? thanks

Comment: Adding a sample file might help...

Comment: I'm not sure how to add a sample file but here is the first 10 lines of code:     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE HorseRacing SYSTEM "HorseRacing.dtd">
<HorseRacing timestamp="20170124T183956+0000">
  <!--
The information supplied within this file forms part of the TurfTV data service. This information is for the sole use of those customers licensed by AMRAC or RMG, subject at all times to the agreements in place between such customers and AMRAC or RMG. Amalgamated Racing Ltd - Official Supplier of British Horseracing Data
-->

Comment: You might upload it to a service like OneDrive or Dropbox, share the file and post the link here?